Can BearSSL certstore be loaded from PROGMEM without needing a filesystem?
I have a relative small sketch that makes https requests of a 3rd party API.  This sketch is used by other people in their own homes, so I can't assume any other infrastructure.
Now because I don't control the API server I can't guarantee the CA uses, so I load a complete certstore.  All of the examples I've found use a filesystem (eg LittleFS) to hold the cert file.  This works OK if the ESP8266 can be connected to USB, but I'm not sure how to do this OTA (e.g. with BasicOTA).
Now the sketch is small enough that I can include the certstore content in PROGMEM
e.g.
static const unsigned char certs_ar[] PROGMEM = {
0x21,0x3c,0x61,0x72,0x63,0x68,0x3e,0x0a,0x63,0x61,0x5f,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x2e,0x64,0x65,0x72,0x2f,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x20,0x31,0x37,0x32,0x31,0x37,0x36,
...
0xb4,0x03,0x25,0xbc
};
#define SIZE_OF_CERTS 191944

Currently on startup I write this array out into a filesystem.
  if (!FSTYPE.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed!");
    return;
  }

  if (!FSTYPE.format())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to format!");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Creating cert store");
  File f=FSTYPE.open("/certs.ar","w");
  if (!f)
  {
    Serial.println(F("Can not open file for writing"));
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("Writing");
  // NOTE: f.write(certs_ar);  doesn't work 'cos certs_ar is in PROGMEM 
  PROGMEMprint(f,certs_ar);
  Serial.println("Complete");
  f.close();

I can now do the standard
  int numCerts = certStore.initCertStore(FSTYPE, "/certs.idx", "/certs.ar");

to load the certstore.
I do this so it's easy to do a network update of the code; e.g. if the certstore needs to change the user can just do BasicOTA of the code base and not need to worry about having to push a new filesystem image over the network.
But this seems wasteful because I now have a copy of the same data in PROGMEM and in LittleFS.
Is there any way to initialize the certstore from PROGMEM?  Or, alternatively, any way of using BasicOTA to update the filesystem?

you can certainly upload to SPIFFS over http, there's an example of that, but I'm not sure about lfs...
